# template options for rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

Lets say I have the following in my `routes.rb` file

```
json_request_only = {
  defaults:    { format: :json }, 
  constraints: { format: :json }
}

ajax_server = {
  only: [:create, :destroy]
}.merge(json_request_only)

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'home#index'

  get 'contact/us/:section', to: 'home#contactus', as: 'contact_us'

  resources :uploaded_files, ajax_server

  # only to create/delete shopping carts and only excepts JSON format
  resources :shopping_carts, ajax_server

  resources :item_types, :path => "category", json_request_only do
    member do 
      delete :delete_image
      delete :archive
      patch :recover
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error

```
unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting => ategory", json_request_only do
                                                                       ^
```

What I am trying to do is to have some template options to be used in routing.

#### Question:

How can I approuch this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you will have to merge the options like this

```
resources :item_types, json_request_only.merge(path: "category") do
```